# How do I download my app icon from android studio with 512 px by 512 px dimensions?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console, appicon

I need to download my app icon from android studio which I made in android studio but I don't know how to download it with the background that I added in android studio and how to download it with 512 px by 512 px in high res, does anyone know how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the screenshots

**1.Change to Project**

[image: 1.Change to Project]

**2.You can see your desire app icon with 512px by 512px dimension**

[image: You can see you desire app icon with 512px by 512px dimension]

**3.Locate the file in the explorer**

[image: Locate the file in the explorer]

**Done. Now use it.**

[image: Done. Now use it.]